# How to make sure that my django project is using virtual environment that i created for it?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I know that there is already a question similar to this,but  i think the answer i wanted is not there.

I am new to django.i have created an virtual environment with virtualenv and a django project,but how can we know that my project is using the packages of virtual environment rather than using global packages??please give me some detailed answer.THANKS in advance.

Comment: It would be nice if you explained why the similar questions does not answer your question.

Howerer, you can run pip freeze to see all packages used in the environment you have active.

Answer (score 1):

you make sure you run `/path/to/my_venv/bin/activate` and your command shell prompt should look like `(my_venv) C:\ >`  or `(my_venv) /home/user$` or similar depending on your os

Answer (score 1):

```py
import sys
    print(hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix') or sys.base_prefix != sys.prefix)
```

Try running above code. If **False** you are using global env and if **True** then virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use one of the IDEs to help you with that.
If you use PyCharm for example, it helps you with defining the virtual environment, and then when you open their terminal, it will be starting the venv for you.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html

If you run your commands from the command line/terminal, you need to activate the virtual environment first and then use the python from that venv.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Python/Virtualenv

I usually create a venv folder inside the project root folder (next to the source folder), and I make sure it's ignored in the .gitignore file.