# If i have many different virtual enviroments in my computer, how to make sure a django project is using a specfic one of them?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have established 5 virtual environments in a folder using the command line, and then start a Django project outside of the folder how can I make sure which virtual env I am using in this Django project if the project is not using any virtual env in the folder, how can I change (make some configurations) the project's virtual env to a specific one in the folder?

PyCharm pro will automatically establish the link between Django project and virtual env, but what if I am using a community version, how can I make it clear that which Django project is using which virtual env?

I think I have the same problem in this question from StackOverflow: [How to make sure that my django project is using virtual environment that i created for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61005013/how-to-make-sure-that-my-django-project-is-using-virtual-environment-that-i-crea)

If anyone knows this and could give me some explanation that would be great.

Comment: I have forever been stymied by virtualenv et al being command line tools, and struggling to use them in other circumstances, to such an extent that I wrote a golang application to handle hosting django: https://github.com/craigmj/djaproxy . Doesn't answer your question, but might solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and you awesome app to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for everyone who had offered me a help here, i am new here and i love this community, everyone is so kind and so pantient, thanks developers!

Answer (score 2):

You can create virtuals env like:

```
python3 -m venv myvenv1
# pip install -r requirements.txt
python3 -m venv myvenv2
# pip install -r requirements.txt
```

for serve django (development)

```
source myvenv1/bin/activate

python3 manage.py runserver
```

or

```
source myvenv2/bin/activate
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try your method and attempt to understand the relationship between each virtual env and project. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This takes some guesswork
The first step is that you must use a CMD board from the same path as yours
Let me explain it better to you

I have five virtual environments
Inside each one are my work files
But to start working on my project, I need to activate this virtual environment and then go to the project files themselves.

FROM CMD I'LL WRITE
./Scripts/activate    #win

then I going to file e.g. src

just go to sittings.py file and look at BASE_DIR => this is what is your dir right now

print it out

```
print(BASE_DIR)
```

I hope I understood your problem and helped you understand it more

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, do you mean that if i want to use a virtual env for a django project, the django project folder should always lie under the virtual env folder?

Comment: the file structure should be like: ".\virtual env1\django project1\django files..."

Comment: Yes, you must be in the same dir of env first to active it. then going to src code you working

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i think i have got the idea.